# JList/ListModel getElements not working

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I am having problems with grabbing all the elements of a ListModel, when i try to write the strings to file they output something like the following:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@79b43f[Ljava.lang.String;@79b43f
```

So what am i doing wrong? Here is the code that is causing the grief:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listModel.getSize(); i++)
        {
            String[] temp = listModel.getElementAt(i).toString().split("-");
            bw.write(temp[0]);
            bw.write(temp[1]);

            System.out.println(temp[0]);
        }
```

bw is a bufferedWriter and listModel is a custom list model that I have made.. You may notice I have split the string,, this is because i want to extract two different values from each list row, I have simply done setText(text + "-" + text) in my customCellRenderer implementation in order to enable me to use the "-" char as a delim to extract the two values

```
public class CustomCellRenderer extends JLabel
implements ListCellRenderer
{
    JLabel left, right;
}

public CustomCellRenderer() 
{
    setOpaque(true);
}

@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
{        
    String leftData = ((String[])value)[0];
    String rightData = ((String[])value)[1];

    // simply will not function how i want it to.. GRR
    leftData = String.format("%-50s", leftData);


    setText(leftData + "-   " + rightData);

    if (isSelected)
    {
        setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
        setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
        setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
        setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
    }
    else
    {
        setBackground(list.getBackground());
        setForeground(list.getForeground());
        setBackground(list.getBackground());
        setForeground(list.getForeground());
    }

    return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).
Hard-code the data.

Comment: That looks like you're writing the `toString()` of a couple of `String[]` - what are the elements in `listModel`?

Comment: @amaidment ive added the listModel code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've posted isn't the `ListModel` - it's the `ListCellRenderer`. But this does reinforce the idea that each item in your `JList` is a `String[]` - e.g. you are casting each value in the `JList` to a `String[]` for rendering.

```
String leftData = ((String[])value)[0];
String rightData = ((String[])value)[1];
```

It appears that there is some confusion as to where the the `ListModel` is being populated. Your post/code suggests that you think it is being populated in the `ListCellRenderer` - this is not the case. It is only working out how to display the values already in the `ListModel`.

So, a quick fix could be in the 'code that's giving you grief':

```
String[] temp = (String[]) listModel.getElementAt(i);
bw.write(temp[0]);
bw.write(temp[1]);
```

However, I wouldn't really encourage this, as you'll have unchecked class casts.

Instead, I would suggest you consider why you are populating the `ListModel` with `String[]` in the first place? e.g. are you constructing the `JList` as follows:

```
JList myList = new JList(new String[]{"A","B"}, new String[]{"C","D"});
```

Comment: im using a GUI editor for creating the list so no, im not creating it with strings at the moment... However I just tried the cast to (String[]) and it worked! I swear I tried that before but, yeh it works :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems in your custom list model, listModel.getElementAt(i) returns an array. Please check it and post your custom list model here if you need further assistance.

Comment: ive added my custom list model code to the original question post

Comment: also it returns a single string which i then split based on the '-' character into an array, however values instead seem to be memory references rather than the original string